# Is it possible to mock a method(with parameters) call in XCTest unit test case in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xctest

I am using a third party framework for external accessory in my application. While writing unit test case i need to bypass all the direct calls to the library.

```
//Actual Code i need to mock
    ExternalDevice *device = [extern.devices firstObject];
// Able to mock this using "mock([ExternalDevice class])"

    //myRequest is a request created using third party Library
    self.myRequest = [device accesoryRequestWithReference:@"123456789" error:&error];
// I need to get a mock object of this request that i can pass from my test case
```

Mocking i tried

### Method 1

```
 EXternalDeviceRequest * mockRequest = mock([EXternalDeviceRequest class]);
    id mockDevice = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[EXternalDevice class]];
    [[[mockDevice stub]andCall:@selector(accesoryRequestWithReference:error:) onObject:device]willReturn: mockRequest];
```

### Method 2

```
device = mock([EXternalDevice class]);
 EXternalDeviceRequest * mockRequest = mock([EXternalDeviceRequest class]);
[given([device accesoryRequestWithReference:@"" error:nil]) willReturn: mockRequest];
```

Both are not working. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using OCMock's macro:

```
EXternalDeviceRequest * mockRequest = mock([EXternalDeviceRequest class]);
id mockDevice = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[EXternalDevice class]];
OCMStub([mockDevice accesoryRequestWithReference:[OCMArg any] error:[OCMArg setTo:nil]]).andReturn(mockRequest);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have tried the changes that u have mention but i am getting the following Crash... *** Assertion failure in NSArray *TKArrayArgumentsForInvocation(NSInvocation *__strong)(), /Users/joreid/Development/Mockito/OCMockito/Source/OCMockito/NSInvocation+TKAdditions.m:102
/Users/sram27/Desktop/Assist/28Mar2015/TESTPROJECT/SAMPLE/SAMPLETests/ViewController.m:163: error: -[TestViewController
testMockingExternalLibrary] : failed: caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "-- Unhandled type: ^@"